# Noticebly larger amount of free space reported compared to the graph in Storage view

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac

My MacBook Pro is of 256 GB. Although I haven't used much of it's space, I'm kind of facing an issue. When I click the Apple menu on top left corner and go to `About This Mac > Storage`, it mentions 213 GB free of 256 GB but slightly below there is a bar, which is about half filled (approximately 160 GB acquired).

The most amazing part is 160 GB is being acquired by applications, and I haven't downloaded application more than 6 or 7.

Can anyone tell me why the bar is filled but still it showing I'm left behind with 213 GB? I really appreciate if someone help me out with this.

[image: Screenshot of the Storage view]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes spotlight can mess up that graph.

I would open Finder and use the preferences to change the setting on calculate all folder sizes or use a tool like Daisy Disk to double check the sizes.

If you have that much space used but things are mis-classified, you can reset spotlight and leave the machine running for a few hours as it re-reads the storage contents.

If you don't have that much space used, boot to Recovery HD and run Disk Utility to repair the volume and drive.

Comment: Actually my mac OS is Yosemite if i upgrade it to El Captain, wouldn't this issue will be solved automatically?

Comment: El Capitan will run the disk check for you. It's more risky since you might have apps or extensions that aren't ready for El Cap, but if you have a backup, why not jump. I love El Capitan changes and feel it's a great OS. I did have a backup in case things didn't work, though.