# Why my app use so much GB

Tags: mac

[image]

I don't know why my apps use so much storage I haven't downloaded anything.

Comment: I voted this question down because it does not ask a specific question or the question is unclear. Please take a moment to read [how to write a good question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and see if you can edit your question to be more clear. Don't forget to indicate what platform you're using (Mac, iPhone, iPad) and the OS version. What "app" do you think is filling your hard drive?

Comment: You can't have 1.59 **T**B on a 250 **G**B disk, so something seems wrong here. Does the problem remain after a reboot?

Comment: Also, please run `sudo du -sm /Applications/* | sort -n` in Terminal and add the last 10 lines of output to your question.

Comment: @Frysk I think the problem is perfectly clear, especially considering the screenshot. OP could further clarify by responding to Patrix's requests.

Answer (score 1):

Your spotlight database (or worse - filesystem) is corrupted.

I'll link to some other situations that cover this.

- [About This Mac -> Storage is wrong?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232199/about-this-mac-storage-is-wrong)
- [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)
- [Mac OS is reporting bad free space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192570/mac-os-is-reporting-bad-free-space)
- [Noticebly larger amount of free space reported compared to the graph in Storage view](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209582/noticebly-larger-amount-of-free-space-reported-compared-to-the-graph-in-storage)

The simplest way to resolve this would be to make a backup (if you don't have one), boot to Recovery HD and use Disk Utility to check / repair your disk. Then you can restart the Mac and let it rebuild the spotlight database overnight. Worst case, you can purge the spotlight database if the situation isn't a transient problem with the calculations.